# tinymce b.editor is null, this.params is undefined on FF

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, tinymce

I am integrating tinymce with an application am developing using zend framework.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Load TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $('textarea.editor').tinymce({
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url : '<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_src.js',

            // General options
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

This is working fine on Chrome. However on FF its printing the following error:

```
b.editor is null
var tinymce=null,tinyMCEPopup,tinyMCE;...yMCEPopup.init();tinyMCEPopup._wait();
tiny_mce_popup.js (line 5)
this.params is undefined
var tinymce=null,tinyMCEPopup,tinyMCE;...yMCEPopup.init();tinyMCEPopup._wait();
tiny_mce_popup.js (line 5)
```

I am not sure why. Am checking that non of the files are giving 404 or any other http errors so if all the scripts are loaded, what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise to not to use the jQuery build! It is really slow when handling typing inputs. It is  better to include the jQuery library first and then the regular tinymce library.

Another thing which will help you to debug your code is to include the development build, which uses the not minified files thus yielding to easier tracable code for debugging. This is what i use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_dev.js"></script>
```

Initialization takes place using:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "textareas", // none, textareas, exact, ...
  theme: "advanced", // also simple available

  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried including the dev version, now the whole page redirects and several errors appear on firebug trying to include files like following:
http://myhost.com/admin/undefined/classes/tinymce.js

The undefined part is the "base", so what do i need to do in order to get this working?